# Can I configure Vagrant to setup a synced folder only if it exists on the host?

Tags: vagrant

For our developers `~/Development/framework_repo` is normally available on the host, but for our designers it wouldn't be. Is it possible to conditionally configure a synced folder depending on it's availability on the host?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since the Vagrantfile is a Ruby script, you could check for the presence of the directory with `File.directory()`, and enable the shared folder only if needed.

For example:

```ruby
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  if File.directory?(File.expand_path("~/Development/framework_repo"))
    config.vm.synced_folder "~/Development/framework_repo", "/guest/path"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using vagrant [conditional environments](http://blog.devteaminc.co/conditional-vagrant-environments/). Additional reading [here](http://blog.lusis.org/blog/2012/12/17/how-we-vagrant/). 
Generally you can create a script that will be run before execution of `vagrant up`. It will test your environment and set proper ENVs that will be further use by vagrant.